# Which is the recommended method to transfer a wordpress site to wordpress Multisite?

Tags: wordpress

I want to create a Wordpress site on my local server and then transfer it into another server that runs a WordPress multisite installation.

Which way is safer to follow:

a) install a WordPress single installation in my local server and after development export it and import it to the WordPress MU which already has a blank site and the theme and plugins installed

b) install a WordPress MU installation in my local server and after development export the specific site and import it to WordPress MU which already has a blank site and the theme and plugins installed

Is any of the above recommended or both are the same?

P.S: the requirements say that WP version has to be 3.6.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go with Option B as that's the best way to avoid any errors.